# Filtering "blank" posts from a user's feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

Is it possible to filter blank posts from a user's feed.  when I say blank I mean a post like this

```
  {
     "id": "<fb post id removed>",
     "from": {
        "name": "<name removed>",
        "id": "<user id removed>"
     },
     "story": "<name removed> likes a link.",
     "story_tags": {
        "0": [
           {
              "id": "<user id removed>",
              "name": "<name removed>",
              "offset": 0,
              "length": 19,
              "type": "user"
           }
        ]
     },
     "type": "status",
     "application": {
        "name": "Likes",
        "id": "2409997254"
     },
     "created_time": "2012-09-07T18:46:36+0000",
     "updated_time": "2012-09-07T18:46:36+0000",
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
```

is there anything in this element of value at all?  It seems to happen when the user likes something on facebook, but what value is it if it doesn't tell me what they liked?

Answer (score 0):

These are known as "story" posts. They used to be optionally enabled/disabled in your app settings but this seems to have gone missing.

The secret here is in the id field. 
You will see it comprises XXXXX_YYYYYY
where XXXXX is the poster's id 
and YYYYYY is the unique identifier.

Now, if you strip the XXXXX_ from the id you will then have the id of the related post. 
Now use the graph API to retrieve this id and all will be revealed.